# Javascript template literals - function call

Tags: javascript, templates, literals

I would like to know if is possible to call function inside a javascript template literals. For those who does not know https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
I have something like this:

```
`<div class="product-card-labels">
    ${statuses.forEach(function(status) { return `<span class="product-card-label">${status.name}</span>` })}
</div>`
```

As you can see I would like to call array.forEach() which should return string to the template.

Comment: Your issue is most likely that you are trying to **define** the function that you are calling inside the `${}`, which also has a nested template literal inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the template syntax right, but are not returning anything in your function call. If you use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the output (instead of [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which returns `undefined`), it'll work fine.

```
`<div class="product-card-labels">
    ${statuses.map(function(status) { return `<span class="product-card-label">${status.name}</span>`; }).join('')}
</div>`
```

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks a lot. I dont understand what is the problem with forEach but map + join works as expected.

Comment: > `forEach()` executes the `callback` function once for each array element; unlike `map()` or `reduce()` it always returns the value `undefined` and is not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the end of a chain.

Comment: > `forEach()` does not mutate the array on which it is called. (However, `callback` may do so)

Comment: (both of those are excerpts from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach))

Comment: ah yes i think i unferstand

Comment: I found one interesting video explaining ES6 template literals here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asRu9MPojFE